# Pass Value from View to Controller - MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a list of thumbnails for the user can select one of the image.

onclick on the thumbnail open a larger image into a form.

What im trying to do now is send the id of the image selected to my controller.

Note: im using MVC 4.

how can i do that?

someone can help with this pls?

Thanks in advance:

Here is my code:

```
 @foreach (var p in ViewBag.Images)
    {           
     <li>
       <a href="~/Files/@p.Name" onclick="swap(this); return false;">
          <img src="~/Files/@p.Name"/>
       </a>
     </li>
}
```

when selected is going this img tag in my form:

```
<img id="main" src="" >
```

using this javascript for this event:

```
function swap(image) {
        document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
    }
```

what i have to do now?

i trying with `<input type="hidden" name="Img_Id" value="Viewbag.??????"/>`
to pass this value to my controller??

Comment: You need to submit it (via POST or GET) back to the Controller action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some terminology help: You can't pass a value from the view to the controller action, the view is rendered after the controller action completes.

What you want to do is pass data from the client (web browser) to a controller action, using form fields.

In your javascript swap method, you could set the value of the Img_Id field to be the value for the selected image. When the form is submitted, the Img_Id will be posted as form data, and can be accepted as a parameter in the action.

You can use JQuery (or something else) to perform the client side actions.

Here's an example (not tested though!):

First add the ID as a data attribute on the element:

```
<a href="~/Files/@p.Name" data-id="@p.ID" onclick="swap(this); return false;">
```

Then some javascript to save that to form (using jquery here):

```
function swap(image) {
    document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
    $("input[name='Img_Id']").val($(image).data("id"));
}
```

Comment: have you an example how to do that?

Comment: @user2232273: updated with an example. FYI, you could also use JQuery to wire up the click event on the links.

Comment: @davesw.. thanks for the example.. i try it but still not pass the value to the controller.. i have to look better how i can put this to work

Comment: @user2232273: Instead of using a hidden form field, use a regular <input type='text'...> You should see the ID value being populated when you click the link (which proves that the client side is working). Once the client side is working, you might have mapping  issues (i.e. wrong name) with the action parameter.

Comment: your code is working. i can see every id of each image i selected in the textbox.. but this value don´t pass to my controller. i get all values except this.

Comment: SOLVED FINNALY!! yeahhh

Comment: @user2232273: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value back to your controller, you either need to submit a form, or else make an AJAX request to your controller.

In the first case, you'd need to update the value of your hidden field with javascript, and then either wait for the user to submit the form, or trigger a submit through javascript depending on what your needs are.

If you want to do an ajax request, it would be more or less the same thing, but you don't need a hidden field to store the value.

Comment: have you an example how to do that?

Comment: Sure. Do you want the user to submit the form manually, or just automatically do something with the image once they click on it?

Comment: i want when the user click on the image open the larger image in my form, and after the user click on the submit button sends the values to my controller.. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery in your swap function. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the official documentation.

If you chose to use this approach, and assuming you place your JavaScript in a separate file, then make sure you get the path for the action and controller and pass that in too.

```
var url = @Url.Action("Index","Home");
```

Therefore you may call: onclick="swap(this.id, url)"